# How the know if the incoming array have different values from the existing one in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am looping through fresh array and my database array. i wanna compare the price and the availability on specific id and date. this is what i got:

```
            foreach ($this->super_unique($data) as $day_info) {

                $data_listing = Array(
                    'list_id' => $airbnb_id,
                    'list_price' => $day_info['price']['local_price'],
                    'list_currency' => $day_info['price']['local_currency'],
                    'list_date' => $day_info['date'],
                    'list_available' => $this->check_list_available((int)$day_info['available'])
                );
                $listings[] = $data_listing;
            }


            if ($this->Reservations_model->existing_prices(@$listings[0]['list_id']) > 0) {
                foreach ($listings as $list_result) {
                    if ($this->db->where("(list_id = '{$list_result['list_id']}' and list_date = '{$list_result['list_date']}' and list_price NOT = '{$list_result['list_price']}' or list_available NOT = '{$list_result['list_available']}')")) {
                        $this->db->where("(list_id = '{$list_result['list_id']}' and list_date = '{$list_result['list_date']}')");
                        $this->db->update('airbnb_lists_price', $list_result['list_available']);
                        $this->db->update('airbnb_lists_price', $list_result['list_price']);
                    }
                }
                echo 'Prices or avilablity change so we need to update';
            } else {
                $this->db->insert_batch('airbnb_lists_price', $listings);
                echo 'Prices not changed all good';
            }

        }
```

Getting me

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`NOT` = '70' or `list_available` `NOT` = 'FALSE') AND (`list_id` = '215583' and ' at line 2

```
UPDATE `airbnb_lists_price` SET `FALSE` = '' WHERE (`list_id` = '215583' and `list_date` = '2015-11-29' and `list_price` `NOT` = '70' or `list_available` `NOT` = 'FALSE') AND (`list_id` = '215583' and `list_date` = '2015-11-29')`
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `NOT =` is not a proper comparison. Have a look at [mysqls non-typed operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/non-typed-operators.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're performing your comparison incorrectly. Using `NOT` is improper here:

```
`list_price` `NOT` = '70' or `list_available` `NOT` = 'FALSE'
```

You can use the not-equals operator one of two ways:

```
`list_price` != '70' or `list_available` != 'FALSE'
```

OR

```
`list_price` <> '70' or `list_available` <> 'FALSE'
```

In addition, `NOT` is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) and you should avoid using those words *in general*. For example, your use of `FALSE` in this portion of the statement:

```
UPDATE `airbnb_lists_price` SET `FALSE` = ''
```

as a column name could be problematic.

Comment: I have fixed this.. but this line is incorrect checking..                     if ($this->db->where("(list_id = '{$list_result['list_id']}' and list_date = '{$list_result['list_date']}' and list_price != '{$list_result['list_price']}' or list_available != '{$list_result['list_available']}')")) {

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments.

Comment: Also, please don't use `@` in your code to suppress error warnings, such as here: `existing_prices(@$listings[0]['list_id']) > 0)`